# Does PWA launching browser gets updated in time

Tags: progressive-web-apps

When a user adds a PWA (Progressive Web Application) to their home screen, is the browser that opens the PWA each time the PWA is launched does ever gets updated?

As a developer I wonder this for reasons including if the new APIs, features will now be available to be used in my PWAs code without workarounds like polyfills etc.

Answer (score 0):

The PWA would be updated inline with the browser. So as soon as the user updates their native browser installation (example Chrome if installed from Chrome) then this update would apply on the PWA too.

If you are referring to updates of your own code, then this would depend on your caching strategy, but usually this would be updated on subsequent reloads as configured in your service worker.